# Add an anouncement or redirect to another SP

Tags: document-library, redirect

I received a request from my manager asking if i can add a  notification within a web part (documents) stating that the library will be moving to another site altogether + link to the new SP.
OR
To redirect when clicking on the Quick Launch from that library to the new SP.

Is this possible? Can anyone provide some guidance on how I could achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a Content Editor Webpart/Script editor webpart on the page. In that webpart, you can add any HTML content.

[image]

In the CEWP/SEWP, you can the HTML like:

```
<a href="url of new doc lib"> Click here to go to updated location </a>
```

To change the Quick launch url, go to Site Settings > Quick launch. Find your document library link and click on Edit to change the URL to the new document library.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the fast answer, i do appreciate it.
The first part was not very clear, i do have installed Web Designer but i can`t quite follow the steps.
The second part i already tried to do,: Edit the link from the Quick Launch and add the one from the new SP.

Comment: Was going to post basically the same but you outraced me. Anyway, since there is no need for two identical answers, I will point out here another little thing that could help. The quick launch fix handles people navigating to the library, while the content editor link on the old library pages should cover people that just type the old address or have it saved as a favourite. For those reason, if the old library isn't to be used anymore, it could be an idea to a) put the old library in "read only mode" by removing all users permissions,  b) if appropiate, hide the document library view web part

Comment: It would be great if the Quick Launch would actually redirect to the new SP but it just does not keep the new URL i am trying to add even if i save it (after i click it, leads me to the same old location)
Is there any way to add a big Anouncement within that web part/library that will contain the link to the new SP ?